# Looking for an HTML Drop Down Select Menu with Autocomplete and remote data support

Tags: javascript, html, web-development, jquery, bootstrap

Can you recommend an HTML/JS/Bootstrap/JQuery Drop Down Select Menu with Autocomplete that accepts the complete list of options from a single remote REST api request as JSON and does not do remote calls when typing.

Comment: Do you have control of the server side?

Answer (score 1):

Perform your [REST request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) first, and parse your JSON with JQuery to [populate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447147/1538254) your `<select>` field.

Finally use any library like [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to enhanced your field with autocomplete.

**Warning**: Initialize the plugin ( `$(".chosen-select").chosen()`) only **after** having populated it.

This will give exactly the behaviour you want.